# Toggle Angular Material DatePicker on MatSelect click and choose the date selected

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to make the material datepicker open automatically when I click on the angular mat-select control.

```
<mat-select formControlName="postDate" (focus)="openCalendar(picker)" (click)="openCalendar(picker)">
  <mat-option value="8555"><i>Delay Crew - 8555</i></mat-option>
  <mat-option value="9000"><i>Self Install - 9000</i></mat-option>
  <mat-option>
    <mat-input-container>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-input-container>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I tried with the focus and click events of the mat-select control this way, it doesn't work.

```
openCalendar(datePicker: MatDatepicker<Date>) {
    datePicker.open();
}
```

Also could someone help with selection, choosing the date should have that date as the option selected in the mat-select control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To automatically open the `DatePicker` when the `select` element is clicked, you can modify your html to look like this:

```
<mat-select formControlName="postDate" (click)="picker.open()">
    <mat-option value="8555"><i>Delay Crew - 8555</i></mat-option>
    <mat-option value="9000"><i>Self Install - 9000</i></mat-option>
    <mat-option>
        <mat-input-container>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-input-container>
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

This works, but the calendar is opened in the wrong position, as the element is moved after the `open()` method has been called. I would probably consider rearranging the elements so that you don't have to deal with this problem (i.e. move the datePicker outside of the select, and place it side by side with it).

**EDIT**

On second thoughts, you can call `picker.open()` when the select element emits the `onOpen` event, this would solve the positioning problem.

```
<mat-select formControlName="postDate" (onOpen)="picker.open()">
    <mat-option value="8555"><i>Delay Crew - 8555</i></mat-option>
    <mat-option value="9000"><i>Self Install - 9000</i></mat-option>
    <mat-option>
        <mat-input-container>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-input-container>
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: @thanks bugs, that worked out. But just wondering how do I make the date selection appear on the mat-select control. Also when clicked once on the first 2 options of the mat-select control it closes the datepicker control doesn't happen to select that option.

Comment: Glad it helped. For the second part of your question, so you want that when the user selects one of the options in the select (which is a Date) the same date is selected in the DatePicker?

Comment: Hey Bugs, When the user selects the date from the datepicker or if the user selects the other 2 options the value should appear on the control as a value been selected.

Comment: Ok I think I understand, when you say on the control, you mean on the mat-select element?

Comment: That's right, It is 2 controls in one[ the datepicker inside the mat-select]. The user could select the date from the datepicker or the first 2 options of the mat-select control, either way the selected value should appear on the mat-select element.

Comment: Are you sure that's a good UX? You might also have to deal with different formats, etc. A valid alternative could be to have two tabs (select and DatePicker), the user can select the appropriate tab depending on what selection method they want to use, and the final value is displayed in a third element

Comment: I was thinking about it as well. The UX doesn't seem to look pretty as of now, and I believe it's going to be a lot of work to get this thing work perfectly. I am going to check out the other option that you mentioned. Thanks bugs.